# "Content Place Holder" in PHP?

Tags: php, master-pages

I have the following PHP/HTML source (in the `template.php` file) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<?php echo 'Hi!';?>
</header>
<article>    <!--Content goes here! -->
</article>
<footer> some text
</footer>
</body>
<html>
```

I add this to my php page via iclude command `<?php include('layouts/template.php');?>`

My question is if there is any way that the content in current php page will be inside the `<article>` tag without separate the code to some files?

(Like the MasterPage in .net/aspx?)

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: You are asking about PHP but give context in different languages without exactly explaining what you're looking for: *"(Like the MasterPage in .net/aspx?)"* - I wish you clarify your question now.

Comment: there are many PHP frameworks that work with viewscripts. for instance ZendFW allows you to set placeholders in the viewscript, but if you don't want to use a framework as big as Zend, you might want to look into smarty and the like...

Comment: The manual also covers this topic: [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like

```
function content($header,$article,$footer){

    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
         <header>'.$header.'</header>
         <article>'.$article.'</article>
         <footer> .'$footer.' </footer>
      </body> 

    <html>';
}
```

and then call that function

```
content("header you want","some article","some footer");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! but is there any other solution without parameters and functions?

Comment: if content is static i mean you wont change then yes you can do without parameter otherwise parameter is only choice except you are getting data from GET/POST/Cookie